# Is this the right way to get a randomized rounding solution?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I would like to implement the randomized rounding algorithm in Python.

The algorithm is quite easy to describe.

> Given a vector, x, of size n where each element, x[i], of x is a real number between 0 and 1. Generate a 0-1 vector, y, of size n where each element of y, y[i], is either 0 or 1 as follows:
>
> for i = 1 to len(x) do: set y[i] = 1 with probability x[i] and y[i] = 0 with probability 1 - x[i].

I tried to do this as follows but I guess I miss somethings or maybe there is quicker/better way:

```
import numpy
n = 4
x = [0.01, 0.6, 0.1, 0.7]
y = numpy.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    randomNum = numpy.random.uniform()
    if randomNum >= x[i]:
        y[i] = 1
    else:
        y[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
x = np.array([0.1, 0.3,0.5, 0.7, 0.9])
y = np.random.rand(len(x)) <= x
```

The first line sets up x, the second line chooses probabilities uniformly at random, and binarizes the result according to the probability/threshold in x[i].

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's how to implement that algorithm in core Python:

```
from random import random

x = [0.01, 0.6, 0.1, 0.7]
y = [int(random() < u) for u in x]
```

But I suspect that the Numpy solution will be somewhat faster, especially when `x` is large. :)